# php, requiring files above 1 hierarchy

Tags: php

I am new to php programming, i am very happy that you are taking your time to answer this newbie question.
As for my question, is it possible for me to "require" a file thats above a 1 level hierarchy?

What do i mean
Lets assume this is a file hierarchy

> Folder->(Html, Includes, Templates)->Html->Project1->index.php

Now, how can i access the includes folder from over here?
I know that from the HTML folder's `index.php` I can just do 
`require("../includes/config.php");` but i want to get it from project1's `index.php`, is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Try `../../includes/config.php` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you are looking to reference a folder thats 2 folders above instead of one, you can just use `../../includes/config.php`

Whats going on:
Essentially,  `..` is linux shorthand for parent folder. So, by using `..` multiple times, you can move higher and higher up in your folder hierarchy, until your in a parent that is shared by the current file and the one you are trying to include.

You can actually use any valid filepath for include, so even a hard reference (eg `/var/public/myinclude.php`) woudl work. This is very bad practice, however, because it breaks yoru codes portability - if you move it to a different server it will break unless that server is identical.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i appreciate the swift response. I want to pick all three as the correct answer but i can pick only one, will mark correct as soon as 4 minutes are up.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an additional "directory level" `../`  for each folder you need to go up. So for `project1/index.php`, you would do the following:

```
require("../../includes/config.php");
```